# ColdFusion: Add CFSELECT dynamically to document with the push of a button

Tags: javascript, coldfusion

Right now I am on a project with a merchant solution service on the back end. Unfortunately I goofed up. Initially we didn't think we would have to populate any form fields that we 'generated' after the site had loaded. So I simply used some javascript to create additional form entries with the click of a button. This worked fine, and we could use anything the user put in there to upload to the database from ColdFusion.

But our management did not give us proper design requirements. He just came back and said "Ok, now just add some drop downs so they can select the version". I think you can see the problem here. Now we need to populate *some* of the dynamic form fields with information from the server. Ergo a client side solution is now basically down the crapper.

So I come to for you help friends. Is there a way to still retain the functionality of what I've done with the JS with a ColdFusion equivalent? I know that there must be, but I'm trying to find a simple conversion.

Here's how the addInput.js file looks:

```
// JavaScript Document
var counter = 0;
var UID = counter + 1;
var limit = 3;
function addInput(divName){
     if (counter == limit)  {
          alert("You have reached the limit of adding " + counter + " inputs");
     }
     else {
          var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
          newdiv.innerHTML = "<input type='hidden' value='new' name='Detail_ID'>"
                         + "<input type='text' value='' name='level' maxlength=255  PASSTHROUGH='style=width:640;color:#editcolor#' TABINDEX='5'>"
                         +"<input type='text' value='' name='offer' maxlength=255  PASSTHROUGH='style=width:640;color:#editcolor#' TABINDEX='5'>"
                         +"<input type='text' value='' name='disclaimer' maxlength=255  PASSTHROUGH='style=width:640;color:#editcolor#' TABINDEX='5'>";
                         "<CFSELECT NAME = 'version_no' QUERY = VersionList VALUE = 'code' DISPLAY = 'description' SELECTED = #version_no# ></CFSELECT>"
          document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv);
          counter++;
     }
}
```

And here is the button which creates it on the main .cfm page:

```
<input type="button" value="Add Another VIP Level" onClick="addInput('dynamicInput');">
```

Comment: You're trying to mix server and client side scripting. CF is rendered on the server and sent to the client, once it's on the client, no more CF. You can accomplish what you're trying to do using a cfc and ajax.

Comment: Ok, I'm not sure you read what I said correctly. I want to take the functionality of this JS script and create a Coldfusion equivalent. I know full well the implications of mixing client side and server side.

To avoid those pitfalls I simply want to recreate the functionality of the aforementioned javascript with coldfusion.

Comment: You can't take something done in JS, in most cases, this being one of those, and redo it in CF. Again, you can accomplish what you're tring to by hitting a cfc with an ajax call to generate what cfselect normally would. Googling that will find you plenty of examples.

Answer (score 1):

I think your question shows a misunderstanding of how CF, and really any application server works. Your browser sends a request to the Server, the server reads the coldfusion but uses it to generate html, which is sent back to your browser. Without requesting another page, and another round trip to the server, there is no way to have coldfusion do anything for you.

But fear not, there is something you can do. Load up a JS framework and fire off an AJAX command to a cfm that would only have your cfselect code in it. It can return you HTML which you can then use JS to inject directly into your page.